# How can we clone a git repository in node_modules when we do npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

How can we clone a git repository when we install our dependency in npm.

```
"dependencies": {
    "<Mydependency>": "<some git url>",
    "promise": "^7.0.3",
    "react": "^0.14.8",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^0.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.8",
    "react-mixin": "^2.0.2"
  },
```

Comment: Have you tried using scripts->preinstall in your package.json to run required git operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:
in the package.json

Without password:

```
"Mydependency": "git+https://<somegiturl.git>#<branch>"
```

with password:

```
 "Mydependency": "git+https://<userName>:<password>@bitbucket.org/myrepo.git#<branch>"
```

Comment: Sadly, this only gets the files. It doesn't do an actual "clone".